# Mixing Simple Injector Scopes in MVC, Web API and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject, simple-injector

I would like to migrate my setup with Ninject to SimpleInjector.
At the moment I have a custom library which is referenced from 
- an ASP.NET MVC application
- an ASP.NET Web API application

This library has a NinjectModule implementation which features some declaration like the following

```
Bind<MyDataContext>().To<MyDataContext>().InRequestScope();
```

My question is relative to the InRequestScope() lifetime. As I read on the SimpleInjector documentation, for the [ASP.NET MVC application](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html) is suggested to use `WebRequestLifestyle` as the `DefaultScopedLifestyle` option while is suggested AsyncScopedLifestyle for the [Web API](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html).

Also when using Owin, which is my case in both the apps, the docs suggests to wrap everything within a block like

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)) {
        await next();
    }
});
```

For my understanding this means:

1. every registration should be registered with the `Lifestyle.Scoped` lifestyle
2. Both the applications should allow scoped instances to be resolved through the `app.Use( ... )` code block

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> every registration should be registered with the Lifestyle.Scoped lifestyle

All registrations that would have been `InRequestScope` in Ninject can now be registered as Lifestyle.Scoped in Simple Injector.

> Both the applications should allow scoped instances to be resolved through the app.Use( ... ) code block

When the `app.Use( ... )` code block with the `AsyncScopedLifestyle` is applied to all requests, this means that MVC code can run within an Async Scope as well. This means that you don't need the `WebApiRequestLifestyle` anymore and can use `AsyncScopedLifestyle` for your MVC application as well.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot Steven!

Comment: why would every registration be `Lifestyle.Scoped`? Does that mean I can have `singleton` services in addition to `scoped` ones?

Comment: I updated my answer to make it clearer what I meant. Obviously not all registrations in ypur application will ve scoped.

Comment: Thanks Steven that makes sense. Coming from asp.net core DI I must admit I failed to grab the meaning of `InRequestScope` from context.